# How to show Ckeditor View on the user side without toolbar

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am having difficulty in showing CKEditor edited content on the view page.

I have tried setting it disabled but this still shows the toolbar with disabled plugins.
I want to show the content without the toolbar as an article.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the config.js file in the directory where you put the source files to specify custom toolbars.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
   config.toolbar = 'Custom'; //makes all editors use this toolbar
   config.toolbar_Custom = []; //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
};
```